# make Bazel use python 3

Tags: python-3.x, bazel

I would like to run my py_test with python 3 in Bazel.

```
py_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.py"]
)

py_test(
    name = "foo_test",
    srcs = glob(["foo_test.py",]),
    deps = [":foo"]
)

py_runtime(
    name = "python-3.6.3",
    files = [],
    interpreter_path = "/usr/local/bin/python3",
)
```

I was able to achieve this using command

```
bazel test --python_top=//path/to/foo:python-3.6.3 foo_test
```

However, I would like to import python3 to bazel sandbox with new_http_archive and  provide the interpreter_path for the py_runtime rule that points to that http_archive within bazel sandbox. So far I am not able to find what is the interpreter_path... Do I have to reference the http_archive label somewhere from the py_runtime or somewhere else?

```
new_http_archive(
name = "python_version",
urls = ["https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tgz"],
strip_prefix = "Python-3.6.3",
build_file_content = """
py_library(
    name = "python_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["Lib/*.py"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)"""
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tgz that you're downloading doesn't contain an interpreter. It contains the source code for the interpreter. If you want to build the interpreter as part of your build, you could do something like this

```
new_http_archive(
    name = "python_version",
    urls = ["https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tgz"],
    strip_prefix = "Python-3.6.3",
    build_file_content = """
genrule(
    name = "build_python",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    outs = ["python"],
    cmd = "./external/python_version/configure && make && cp python $@",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)""",
)
```

And then your py_runtime rule would set the `interpreter` attribute (not interpreter_path):

```
py_runtime(
    name = "python-3.6.3",
    files = [],
    interpreter = "@python_version//:python",
)
```

Comment: Thank you, being that this approach isn't cross platformI will stick to having  "/usr/local/bin/python3" , although I am wondering if there is a way to have Bazel use environment variable for py_home?

Comment: What platforms do you care about? This should work on most types on Linux. For Mac or Windows, you could create alternative new_http_archives  that fetch the installers. And then your py_runtime rule could have a select statement on the interpreter to chose which one to use based on platform.

Comment: I care about all the platforms. I found another way to enforce python 3 with `--python_path=/usr/local/bin/python3 --force_python=py3` when `srcs_version ="PY3"`, so I will use that for now (trying to get `--python_path` to accept environment variable) and may try your approach later to see if it works. Thanks!