# Running Android app using Bazel fails due to python import

Tags: android, bazel

I've written a basic Android app with Bazel as my build system, using this documentation as my guide: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/android-app.html.

All has gone well until I reach the final step and attempt to run my app using:

```
bazel mobile-install //src/main:app
```

This results in the following error:

```
/home/mstagitis/Documents/pollapp/src/java/com/pollapp/app/android/BUILD:15:15: Generating incremental installation manifest for //java/com/pollapp/app/android:AndroidApp failed: (Exit 1): build_incremental_dexmanifest failed: error executing command bazel-out/k8-py2-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/android/build_incremental_dexmanifest bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/java/com/pollapp/app/android/AndroidApp_files/dexmanifest.txt ... (remaining 1 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox build_incremental_dexmanifest failed: error executing command bazel-out/k8-py2-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/android/build_incremental_dexmanifest bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/java/com/pollapp/app/android/AndroidApp_files/dexmanifest.txt ... (remaining 1 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mstagitis/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mstagitis/1a9dfe406f86559011381ab7ff487e39/sandbox/linux-sandbox/44/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-py2-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/android/build_incremental_dexmanifest.runfiles/bazel_tools/tools/android/build_incremental_dexmanifest.py", line 35, in <module>
    from queue import Queue
ImportError: No module named queue
Target //java/com/pollapp/app/android:AndroidApp failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.227s, Critical Path: 0.14s
INFO: 5 processes: 5 internal.
```

It looks like the failure is due to a bad import statement:

```
from queue import Queue
```

I know that 'Queue' was switched to 'queue' in Python3. Is there any way to force Bazel to use Python3 to bypass this error?

**Edit:** Here is the full error when run with --verbose_failures

```
ERROR: /home/mstagitis/Documents/pollapp/src/java/com/pollapp/app/android/BUILD:15:15: Generating incremental installation manifest for //java/com/pollapp/app/android:AndroidApp failed: (Exit 1): build_incremental_dexmanifest failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/mstagitis/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mstagitis/1a9dfe406f86559011381ab7ff487e39/sandbox/linux-sandbox/4/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/home/mstagitis/.cache/bazelisk/downloads/bazelbuild/bazel-4.0.0-linux-x86_64/bin:/home/mstagitis/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/mstagitis/Programs/Android/Sdk/tools \
  bazel-out/k8-py2-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/android/build_incremental_dexmanifest bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/java/com/pollapp/app/android/AndroidApp_files/dexmanifest.txt bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/java/com/pollapp/app/android/_dx/AndroidApp/classes.dex.zip)
Execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox build_incremental_dexmanifest failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/mstagitis/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mstagitis/1a9dfe406f86559011381ab7ff487e39/sandbox/linux-sandbox/4/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/home/mstagitis/.cache/bazelisk/downloads/bazelbuild/bazel-4.0.0-linux-x86_64/bin:/home/mstagitis/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/mstagitis/Programs/Android/Sdk/tools \
  bazel-out/k8-py2-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/android/build_incremental_dexmanifest bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/java/com/pollapp/app/android/AndroidApp_files/dexmanifest.txt bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/java/com/pollapp/app/android/_dx/AndroidApp/classes.dex.zip)
Execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mstagitis/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mstagitis/1a9dfe406f86559011381ab7ff487e39/sandbox/linux-sandbox/4/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-py2-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/android/build_incremental_dexmanifest.runfiles/bazel_tools/tools/android/build_incremental_dexmanifest.py", line 35, in <module>
    from queue import Queue
ImportError: No module named queue
Target //java/com/pollapp/app/android:AndroidApp failed to build
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Martin. Unfortunately I don't own the code and can't make that change.

This is Bazel code that is being executed: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel.


I pull this code in using Bazel's http_archive rule: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_archive.

Comment: This may be based upon a build environment that is not sane (alike providing the wrong python version). I'll reopen that question, but please add the output of `--verbose_failures`.

Comment: Hey Martin - I added the full error to the original question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not specifying a python interpreter in my build. Maybe the default is PY2? Is there a way to explicitly upgrade this to PY3?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47044164/549372

Comment: I just realized that I can get past this issue using this flag: --incompatible_use_python_toolchains=false. Is there a way to make this the default? It doesn't seem like I'd need to pull in the python version (like the link you shared) if it's already there.